# Data initialization doesn't work in spring boot hibernate app

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am learning spring boot and trying my first sample app but have stuck on initialization of data. I am able to create tables but my data.sql file is not executing.
Following is my Application file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Category:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //Travel, Grocery,...
    private String name;

}
```

data.sql:

```
insert into category values (1,'Travel')
insert into category values (2,'Auto Loan')
insert into category  values (3,'Travel')
```

Controller:

```
    package com.example.codeengine.expense.controller;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.codeengine.expense.model.Category;
import com.example.codeengine.expense.repository.CategoryRepository;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CategoryController {
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public CategoryController(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        super();
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/categories")
    Collection<Category> categories(){
        System.out.println(categoryRepository.findAll());
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Does adding getter/setter and constructor help you out?

Comment: but I am using Lombok. Shouldn't it take care of getter/setter on the go?

Comment: Have you used getter/setter annotations?

Comment: Not yet, let me try this

Comment: Getter/Setter annotation didn't work for me but when I generated getter and setters by right-clicking I was able to get the data. How should I use Getter/Setter annotation without needing to add getter and setters?

Comment: I have written an answer to show how to use Getter/Setter annotation. Please check and let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add getter-setters to retrieve and set the data.

Either you can manually add getter-setters in `Category` class or you if you are using `Lombok` then you need to add annotations at class level as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Data
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //Travel, Grocery,...
    private String name;

}
```

I have added annotation for **getter-setter, constructors and toString method**.

Comment: I have copied code shared by you but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I only get [{},{},{}]

Comment: Keep Data and Table annotation only. Remove rest as Data with itself take care of getter/setter, constructor and toString method. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Do one thing, remove  all irrelevant annotation at class level. You better add getter/setter annotation at field level then let me know.